# Udevrule doesn't work as expected, and I don't understand why

Tags: linux, udev

I'm trying to use `udev` to invoke a script every time a bluetooth device is connected. Here is what I've done so far.

I created a `bluetooth.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. `bluetooth.rules` itself contains only one line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", RUN+="/path/to/myscript"
```

I expect this to run every time a bluetooth connection is formed *and* terminated; the problem is that the script is only invoked for the latter case, not the former.

Here is `udevadm monitor`'s output at the moment a connection was formed (right after I ran `bluetoothctl connect <MAC address>`):

```
KERNEL[71481.889315] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [71481.903034] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[71482.495175] add      /devices/virtual/input/input45 (input)
KERNEL[71482.495248] add      /devices/virtual/input/input45/event24 (input)
UDEV  [71482.496423] add      /devices/virtual/input/input45 (input)
UDEV  [71482.591539] add      /devices/virtual/input/input45/event24 (input)
```

And at the moment the device was disconnected:

```
KERNEL[71553.849145] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input45/event24 (input)
UDEV  [71553.850872] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input45/event24 (input)
KERNEL[71553.919022] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input45 (input)
UDEV  [71553.919624] remove   /devices/virtual/input/input45 (input)
KERNEL[71556.168971] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [71556.179602] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
```

Here is the result after running `udevadm info --attribute-walk --path`:

```
$ udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256':
    KERNEL=="hci0:256"
    SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0':
    KERNELS=="hci0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="bluetooth"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11/3-11:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-11:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="btusb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-11':
    KERNELS=="3-11"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="6"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="11"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="07dc"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="8087"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="63390"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="2"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="2000"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="327300"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/persist}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="63920"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="263050"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1227"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0515"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 5.15.68-1-lts xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="15"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="1310670"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="71736870"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="1309771"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="70427094"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="4538"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x8c31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="30"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/30}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="71737713"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{resource0}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x04"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x2211"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

The script invoked is nothing too complicated. It's basically a one-liner containing a single call to `pkill` to send a signal to another process.

I don't understand why the script wasn't invoked at the moment a device was connected

My intuition tells me that this has something to do with the order of the udev events (which seems to follow the LIFO model, based on `udevadm monitor`'s output), though I could be way off the mark.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1) Can you check if the script execution fails? Does the script work per se? 2) You did not define any `ACTION`. Maybe specify `ACTION=="add"` to ensure it is actually invoked during the correct event.

Comment: @FelixJN Yes. I can confirm that the script did not execute (I added an extra line in the script that launches a terminal and prints out a message). I also added ACTION=="add" into the .rule file. Didn't work also. I also reloaded udev with udevadm control --reload-rules. When that didn't help, I rebooted the machine, and still the rule wasn't executed. At this point, I'm just confused.

Comment: UDEV is run as root, so launching a terminal would usually fail. Better add some `{date ; echo "UDEV-rule test" ;} >> /home/Anthony/udev-testfile` to test for the execution. Maybe the error is there altogether: setting the correct user for execution. Maybe share the script if psossible?